# Sobre tag para banco de dados MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-tags

Bom dia!

Galera! To com banco de dados mais de 25 mil registros. Estou reformulando o banco de dados por está muito desorganizado então to construindo um script para fazer tudo automático porque fazer 1 por 1 não rola né.

A dúvida é seguinte, possui um campo texto, nesse campo existe tag's

mas na hora de iniciar o processo ele está convertendo ou removendo tag's.

Ela está gravando seguinte forma `<b>` para `&lt;b&gt;`

O que eu quero é `<b>` para `<b>`

Ela não pode converter ou remover, o que fazer?

Segue o script.

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

    $texto = htmlentities(str_replace('\'', '"', $r['artigo']), ENT_QUOTES);
    $qy = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO posts SET titulo='{$titulo}', texto='{$texto}', chamada='{$r['chamada']}', view='{$r['visto']}', categoria='{$t}', img='{$r['id']}.jpg', data='{$r['dat']}', destaque='{$destaque}', link='{$link}'") or die(mysql_error());

}
```

Comment: então não pode usar htmlentities. Exemplo $texto = "<b>texto</b>"  htmlentities($texto)  &lt;b&gt;texto&lt;/b&gt;

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo mas qual maneira de fazer então? Pois se eu tirar htmlentities elas são enviado apenas texto. Quero enviar com tags.

Comment: Realmente é difícil explicar, vou tentar explicar novamente. Exemplo: puxando informações do banco e jogando direto para banco os tags some. Se eu utilizar htmlentities elas são convertidos. Deu pra entender agora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer que grave, no banco, sua variável $texto com todas as tags do HTML, portanto, tem que mandar gravar seu  $texto sem a função htmlentities.

Faz só o replace   `$texto =  str_replace('\'', '"', $r['artigo']);`

Comment: já conseguir resolver, era só tirar htmlentities e tive que fazer uma gambiarra converter palavras

Comment: Pois então, é o que eu disse desde o primeiro comentário "então não pode usar htmlentities."